# HOw to remove child div tag with runat=server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div tag with runat="server".
with another div tag which is added dynamically.
eg:

> `<div id="div1" runat="server">`
>   `<div></div>`--this div tag is addded dynamically</div>

what i observed is that i am not able to remove the div tag if i add it dynamically... closing div tag(`</div>`) is not rendering. if its a static div i am able to remove that.

Please let me know.

Comment: Where are you attempting to remove the <div/> tag? On the server or the client?

Comment: Unless we see your JQuery that removes the item, and (if dynamically added on the client) you JQuery to add the div, we can only give general advice.

Answer (score 0):

If the inner div cannot be removed, the problem would be with your selector or timing.  If it was dynamically added on the server, it definitely would be the selector.  If it was dynamically added on the *client*, it could be either the selector or a timing issue (when was it created?).